# Django Converting HttpResponse to PDF for multiple Instances And Zipping them not working

Tags: python, django, zip, xhtml2pdf

I'm trying to get multiple instances from a query set, then for each instance, create a PDF from a HttpResponse object using the [xhtml2pdf](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package, then eventually zip all of the generated PDFS for download.

This is what I have so far:

```
def bulk_cover_letter(request, ward_id, school_cat_id):
    report_files = {}
    school_type = SchoolType.objects.get(id=school_cat_id)
    ward = Ward.objects.get(id=ward_id)

    schools_in_school_type = Applicant.objects.filter(
     school_type=school_type, ward_id=ward_id, award_status='awarded').order_by().values_list(
     'school_name', flat=True).distinct()

    for school in schools_in_school_type:
        cheque_number = Applicant.objects.filter(school_type=school_type, ward_id=ward_id, award_status='awarded', school_name=school).values_list('cheque_number__cheque_number', flat=True).distinct()
        beneficiaries = Applicant.objects.filter(school_type=school_type, ward_id=ward_id, award_status='awarded', school_name=school)
        total_amount_to_beneficiaries = Applicant.objects.filter(school_type=school_type, ward_id=ward_id, award_status='awarded', school_name=school).aggregate(total=Sum('school_type__amount_allocated'))

        context = {
            'school_name' : school,
            'beneficiaries' : beneficiaries,
            'total_amount_to_beneficiaries' : total_amount_to_beneficiaries,
            'title' : school + ' Disbursement Details',
            'cheque_number': cheque_number[0]
        }

        response = HttpResponse('<title>Cover Letter</title>', content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "%s.pdf" %(cheque_number[0])
        content = "inline; filename=%s" %(filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        template = get_template('cover_letter.html')
        html = template.render(context)

        mem_fp = io.BytesIO()
        pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(
            html, dest=mem_fp, link_callback=link_callback)
        resp = HttpResponse(mem_fp.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
        resp['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" %(filename)
        report_files[filename] = resp

    mem_zip = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(mem_zip, mode="w") as zf:
        for filename, content in report_files.items():
            zf.writestr(filename, content)
    response = HttpResponse(mem_zip, content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(f'{ward}_cover_letters.zip')

    return response
```

Everything works fine until the zipping part. I'm getting the error:

> object of type 'HttpResponse' has no len()

How do I go about that?

Comment: What machine are you working on? Most (if not all) Linux distros have `zip` command pre-installed so you can zip directly from terminal. If this is the case you can perform zipping using that command and the `subprocess` module.

Comment: This is in a django context. Ideally this should be working in a browser